# fitting semivariogram using R

Tags: r, geor

I've fitted my semivariogram using "geoR" package as follows:

```
#loading geoR
library(geoR)
#calculating the semivariogram
bin1 <- variog(geodata)
#plotting
plot(bin1)
#fitting the model
lines.variomodel(cov.model = "exp", cov.pars = c(0.571,0.2527), nug = 0.13, max.dist=1)
```

Is there any way to know the goodness-of-fit of the exponential model (with ease)??

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: not really a programming question?  ( http://stats.stackexchange.com ?)

Comment: also see http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Fitting-nested-variograms-to-empirical-variograms-td2761505.html

Comment: I'd say not really fitting a variogram (drawing perhaps)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't really fitting the model here, you can use `variofit` to fit a model to the empirical semivariogram.

eg

```
library(geoR)
vario100 <- variog(s100, max.dist=1)
ini.vals <- expand.grid(seq(0,1,l=5), seq(0,1,l=5))
ols <- variofit(vario100, ini=ini.vals, fix.nug=TRUE, wei="equal")
## variofit: model parameters estimated by OLS (ordinary least squares):
## covariance model is: matern with fixed kappa = 0.5 (exponential)
## fixed value for tausq =  0 
## parameter estimates:
## sigmasq     phi 
##  1.1070  0.4006 
## Practical Range with cor=0.05 for asymptotic range: 1.200177
## 
## variofit: minimised sum of squares = 0.1025
```

You could calculate the appropriate weighted sum of squares your self at each of the points on the variogram using cov.spatial.

I don't think this is a good idea.

---

Instead, you could use `loglik.GRF` to calculate the likelihood associated with a given model and all the data

```
# you can pass an existing model
loglik.GRF(s100, obj.model = ols)
## [1] -87.32958
```

Or just the parameters

```
 loglik.GRF(s100, cov.pars = c(1.5,0.6), nugget = 0.01)
```

---

If you really want the weighted least squares value, you can use `fit.variogram` from the `gstat` package, without actually fitting anything.

One good thing is that `gstat` has some helper functions to convert from `geoR` models to `gstat` versions. This is really useful as `gstat` is much faster and more efficient for prediction.

eg

```
 library(gstat)
 # convert geodata to  data.frame object
 s100df <- as.data.frame(s100)
 # remove geodata.frame class that causes problems
 class(s100df) <- 'data.frame'

 # create gstat version of variogram
 s100v <- variogram(data~1, ~X1+X2, s100df)

 # convert a variomodel to vgm object

 foo <- as.vgm.variomodel(list(cov.model = 'exponential', kappa = 0.5,
                          cov.pars = c(1.5,0.6), nugget = 0.2))

 # get the weighted least squares value
 # calling fit.variogram without fitting any thing
 fittedfoo <- fit.variogram(s100v, foo, fit.sills = FALSE, fit.ranges = FALSE)
 # the weighted sum of squares is
 attr(fittedfoo, 'SSErr')
 ## [1] 0.6911813
```

Comment: you are right, but actually I can know the error associated with fitting by just adding lines to my semivariogram with an exponential model, though I could have fitted my empirical variogram with ordinary (OLS) and/or weighted (WLS) least squares models using the variofit function.